# Chained State city dropdown list from JSON

Tags: json, parsing, jquery

I am trying to populate a chained State City select dropdowns. I am using an external json file to do so, which consists of State and their corresponding city name, id and pincode. Can somebody gimme some idea on how to achieve this. I need to populate the city and pincode value based on the state selection. Thanks in advance...

### JSON

```
{
"Alaska" : [
            {"id": "1", "name": "Adak", "pincode": "xxx1"},
            {"id": "2", "name": "Akhiok", "pincode": "xxx2" },
            {"id": "3", "name": "Akiak", "pincode": "xxx3" },           
       ],

"Arizona" : [
            {"id": "4", "name": "Apache Junction", "pincode": "xxx4"},
            {"id": "5", "name": "Avondale", "pincode": "xxx5"},
            {"id": "6", "name": "Benson", "pincode": "xxx6"},
        ],

"Alabama" : [
            {"id" : "5", "name": "Abbeville", "pincode": "xxx7" },
            {"id" : "7", "name": "Adamsville", "pincode": "xxx8" },
            {"id" : "8", "name": "Akron", "pincode": "xxx9" },
        ]
}
```

### Final rendered html

```
<select id="state">
      <option value="1">Alaska</option>
      <option value="2">Arizona</option>
      <option value="3">Alabama</option>
      </select>

      <select id="city">
      <option value="4">Adak</option>
      <option value="5">Akhiok</option>
      <option value="6">Akiak</option>
      </select>

      <input id="pincode" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your question interesting and wrote the corresponding solution which you can see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jQuery/DependendSelectsFromJson.htm).

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var myData;
    var onCityChange = function (e) {
        var cityData = $("option:selected", e.target).data('pincode');
        $("#pincode").val(cityData.pincode);
    };
    var onStateChange = function (e) {
        var state = $("option:selected", e.target).text();
        if (state && myData) {
            var stateData = myData[state];
            if (stateData && stateData.length > 0) {
                $("#city").empty();
                $("#city").unbind('change');
                for (var i = 0; i < stateData.length; i++) {
                    var cityData = stateData[i];
                    var option = $('<option value="' + cityData.id + '">' + cityData.name + '</option>')
                                    .data('pincode', cityData);
                    $("#city").append(option);
                }
                $("#city").bind('change', onCityChange)
                            .trigger('change');
            }
        }
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'DependendSelectsFromJson.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var stateOptions = "", stateId = 1;
            for (var prop in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    stateOptions += '<option value="' + stateId + '">' + prop + '</option>';
                    stateId++;
                }
            }
            myData = data;
            $("#state").html(stateOptions)
                .bind('change', onStateChange)
                .trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

to get access about the `pincode` of the second (city) select box I used [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function which I find very practical if one need to associate some additional information with an DOM element. One could save only `pincode` value in the way, but I used the function to save full information about the city.

**UPDATED**: I forgot to mention that the JSON data which you posted has errors. You should remove commas before ']'. Probably it is just a problem with cut&paste of the data to the text of the question.

Comment: If the json file is pre-rendered even before the user arrives at state/city selection page, would it anyway have some lag in performance if the dataset is huge ??

Comment: @Sullan: You should test the performance in your environment. I don't know whether you speak about kilobytes or gigabytes of data. If the test will shows performance problems you can load only the list of states in the first ajax call and load the cities in the next ajax call instead of the usage of previously saved `myData` array.

Comment: @Oleg what should be the case if i want to add one more parameter for state/province id ?? Formatted json is as follows..{
"stateid": "AB",            
"id": "1",
            "name": "Adak",
            "pincode": "xxx1" 
        },

Comment: @Sullan: Sorry, I don't exactly understand what you mean. Could you explain what you need? Do you need more `<select>` elements of additional element like `pincode` which should be displayed?

Comment: @Sullan: It seems to me that the information should look more as `"Alaska": {"stateid": "AB", "cities": [{"id": "1", "name": "Adak", "pincode": "xxx1"}, {"id": "2", "name": "Akhiok", "pincode": "xxx2" },{"id": "3", "name": "Akiak", "pincode": "xxx3" }, ... ] }`. In the case you can save in the `data` of the `<options>` of the first `<select>` ("#state") information about the `stateId`. You can do this exactly like I saved the informations to the elements of the second `<select>` ("#city").

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways.

global Varible option.

```
var json_object = {
"Alaska" : {}

}; //and the rest of other text too lazy to type :)

$('#state').change(function(){
  var state =  $(this).val();
  cities = json_object[state];
  $('#city').html('');//remove the prev elements
  for(item in cities){//same as foreach in php
     $('<option value=""></option>').appendTo($('#city'));
  }
});
```

i must admit is not complete but giving you the rough idea.

Other wise use ajax like so

```
$('#state').change(function(){
    var url = 'ajax.php';//should return json with a list of cities only
    var state = $('#state').val();
    var data = {'state':state};
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:data,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(items){
            //do something with it
        }
    })
});
```

The only thing you need to know is that both have their advantages and disadvantages.

first option : can only fire one request but loads sh*t loads of data that are not needed.
second option: makes more request but less data